# Binary vs. multi-class text classification

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataset with social media posts that looks as below, but its in Farsi and I could not find a readily available R/Python sentiment analysis package.

```
post/tweet
"we are tired of this regime and need to make a change happen now"
```

Ideally, I want to classify each statement as having a negative, positive, or neutral sentiment. Therefore, I created a small dictionary where I classify words into either negative or positive ones.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
#install.packages("tidyverse")
#install.packages("stringr")
#install.packages("readxl")
```

### With three categories: positive, negative, and neutral

```
Raw_data_on_posts %>% mutate(p_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$positive, collapse = '|')), 
                 n_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$negative, collapse = '|'))) %>% 
           mutate(label = case_when(p_count > n_count ~ 'positive',
                                    p_count < n_count ~ 'negative',
                                    TRUE ~ 'neutral')) %>% select(post, label)
```

I ended up having most statements as neutral, although based on my reading of the social media posts are either pro or anti the Iranian regime. Specifically, I believe this occurred because it is classifying words that I neither classified as negative nor positive, as neutral. But is it possible to instead only compare whether a statement has more negative or positive words?

```
post/tweet                                 sentiment 
"we are tired of this regime               neutral 
and need to make a change happen now"
```

I wonder if the issue above is caused by R not recognizing/reading Farsi words and letters? I am asking because I ran the same code above to test it with English words below and it worked well:

```
post
<chr>
label
<chr>
bad and good       neutral          
really good        positive         
in the middle      neutral          
bad                negative
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax doesn't appear to have any point where it will account for neutral words, so they are unlikely to make a difference. Tagging posts which don't have any words registering as positive or negative may reveal a problem with your data or positive/negative classes. See if this edit to your code throws up any data that isn't recognised:

```
mutate(label = case_when(p_count > n_count ~ 'positive',
                                    p_count < n_count ~ 'negative',
                                     n_count==0 & p_count== 0 ~ 'Not recognised'
                                    TRUE ~ 'neutral'))
```

Comment: Thanks, the code runs well but does not make a difference as all posts are still neutral. Does it make sense to instead only compare whether a statement has more negative or positive words, and thus classify it as such?
Ex: post with 5 positive words and 8 negative words would be negative.

Comment: That would be a good idea, looking at your syntax it looks like that is what should be happening in theory, with neutral being applied only if neither is larger than the other. Try adding : n_count== p_count== 0 ~ 'Tie' to see if there are lots of data points which are truly equal based on the words you've identified, as this may raise issues with the lists of words you're using.

Comment: Thanks, ran this and all posts are still classified as neutral=:

```{r}
Raw_data_on_posts %>% mutate(p_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$positive, collapse = '|')), 
                 n_count = str_count(post, str_c(Dictionary$negative, collapse = '|'))) %>% 
           mutate(label = case_when(p_count > n_count ~ 'positive',
                                    p_count < n_count ~ 'negative',
                                    n_count= p_count== 0 ~ 'Tie',
                                    TRUE ~ 'neutral')) %>% select(post, label)
```

Comment: If everything's still neutral than I think it's a syntax issue, as something should have had a value assigned to the label column. Have you got values in your p/n columns that agree with what you think would be there?

Comment: I wonder if this issue could be caused by how R is reading the posts in Farsi?
Because I used the same code with English posts as you can see in the updated question and it worked well.

Comment: It's probably how R is reading the posts in Farsi then, it could also be an issue with either the data or the list of words you're using, check that they are formatted in the same way.